QPlaneGeometry and Images
For background, I've been trying to create a 3D rendering of a graph network, but I want to use pictures/symbols/etc as vertices instead of the normal varietals of 3D shapes (spheres, cones, pyramids, etc).
I came across QPlaneGeometry and its associated QPlaneMesh, but I'm not seeing any clear path to putting something simple like a circle/triangle/picture on that plane via its mesh. I'm a bit of a newb at this kinda GUI work, so am I barking up the wrong tree or is there a nifty solution here? Do I have to learn my way around QtQuick land?
